# how can i get trace using gRPC, istio, jaeger, Spring-boot, Java?

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, istio, grpc-java, jaeger

my code:
https://github.com/nikita111100/gRPC-vs-REST

i cant get a trace of all services
I guess grpc-spring-boot-starter can do this without propagate headers

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
@Configuration
```

public class TracingConfig {

```
@GrpcGlobalClientInterceptor
TracingClientInterceptor tracingInterceptor(Tracer tracer) {
    return TracingClientInterceptor
            .newBuilder()
            .withTracer(tracer)
            .build();
}
```

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-grpc